# Ansible import list of dictionaries from a file and loop over each dictionary item

Tags: ansible, pymongo, lookup

I have a pymongo script which generates a output like below (list of dictionaries) which I am storing a file -

```
{'A': 'foo1', 'B': 'bar1', 'C': 'baz1'}
{'A': 'foo2', 'B': 'bar2', 'C': 'baz2'}
{'A': 'foo3', 'B': 'bar3', 'C': 'baz3'}
```

I want to import this file in my playbook and loop over each item. How should I approach this? Can lookup be used somehow?

Comment: The data isn't a list. A list in JSON is closed in brackets `[]` and the elements are separated by comma `,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the list of dictionaries

```yaml
shell> cat data.yml
[{'A': 'foo1', 'B': 'bar1', 'C': 'baz1'},
 {'A': 'foo2', 'B': 'bar2', 'C': 'baz2'},
 {'A': 'foo3', 'B': 'bar3', 'C': 'baz3'}]
```

the tasks

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ lookup('file', 'data.yml')|from_yaml }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.A }} {{ item.B }} {{ item.C }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

give

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item={'A': 'foo1', 'B': 'bar1', 'C': 'baz1'}) =>
  msg: foo1 bar1 baz1
ok: [localhost] => (item={'A': 'foo2', 'B': 'bar2', 'C': 'baz2'}) =>
  msg: foo2 bar2 baz2
ok: [localhost] => (item={'A': 'foo3', 'B': 'bar3', 'C': 'baz3'}) =>
  msg: foo3 bar3 baz3
```

---

It's also possible to use the data

```yaml
shell> cat data.yml
{'A': 'foo1', 'B': 'bar1', 'C': 'baz1'}
{'A': 'foo2', 'B': 'bar2', 'C': 'baz2'}
{'A': 'foo3', 'B': 'bar3', 'C': 'baz3'}
```

The tasks below will give the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ lookup('file', 'data.yml').splitlines()|
                     map('from_yaml')|
                     list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.A }} {{ item.B }} {{ item.C }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

Comment: Thank you! this does the job for me. As my data file is being generated in second form (without comma and brackets). Thank you for the very clear answer.